# Programmatically access children builds in Jenkins build flow

Tags: email, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-build-flow

I have a build flow pipeline (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) setup in Jenkins that spawns two or more children jobs each of which runs Junit tests.

```
def childjobs = []

// some logic to populate the children jobs array

// Run the jobs in parallel
parallel(childjobs)
```

I am trying to write a Groovy script in the context of the parent job using the Jenkins API to send a summary email from the parent job by collecting the summaries from the children.

How can I access the build information (success/failure, how many failures, duration, Junit results etc.) of the children jobs from the parent job? *Conceptually something like this*:

```
for (AbstractBuild<?,?> childjob in childjobs) {
    // get build info from childjob
    // get Junit results from childjob
}
```

Comment: See if this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808181/aggregating-results-of-downstream-is-no-test-in-jenkins

Comment: Thanks @Tuffwer. The information in the posting is mainly about aggregating artifacts from children jobs onto the parent. My requirement is different in that I am trying to access the children job "objects" from the parent job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to play with the Build Flow and Jenkins API, and finally I got this:

```
import hudson.model.*
import groovy.json.*

// Assign a variable to the flow run
def flow = parallel(
  {build("child-dummy", branch_name: "child1")},
  {build("child-dummy", branch_name: "child2")}
)

println 'Main flow ' + flow.getClass().toString() + ', size: ' + flow.size()
flow.each { it ->                                           // type = com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.FlowState  
  def jobInvocation = it.getLastBuild()                     // type = com.cloudbees.plugins.flow.JobInvocation
  println 'Build number #' + jobInvocation.getNumber()  
  println 'Build URL ' + jobInvocation.getBuildUrl()
}
```

To obtain details of the run, such as artifacts etc. from the child jobs, use `jobInvocation.getBuild()` method that returns a `Run` instance.

Getting the Junit results should be easy by parsing the JSON result file as specified in [How to get the number of tests run in Jenkins with JUnit XML format in the post job script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712516/how-to-get-the-number-of-tests-run-in-jenkins-with-junit-xml-format-in-the-post).